# How to change row layout structure based on radio button in Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, swt

I want to show two text boxes based on selection of a radio button using SWT Widget. However, when I will select another radio button the previous textboxes should be hidden and a dropdown should be displayed. I am able to achieve the functionality using setVisibility(true) and false. The main problem here is that when the textboxes are not displayed(on selection of 2nd radio button), the space for them is getting consumed and the dropdown is coming below that. I don't want to waste that much space and want the layouts to overlap and consume a common space allotted to them since both can't be used at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an idea about how to accomplish and just tried it out because of curiosity. So I've created an [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org/) in just 99 lines of code for you. The basic idea to avoid strange behavior is to subclass `Composite` and place the (dis)appearing widgets in there. So there are 3 method necessary: one for creating the first set of widgets, one for the second set, and on for erasing all. After widget manipulation call `layout` for changes to take effect.

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;

public class Foo {
    Shell shell;
    Button button1, button2;
    MyComposite composite;

    public Foo() {
        Display display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        button1 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        button1.setText("Button 1");
        button1.setSelection(true);
        button1.addSelectionListener(new  ButtonListener());

        button2 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
        button2.setText("Button 2");

        composite = new MyComposite();
        composite.createTexts();

        shell.open();
        shell.pack();

        while(!shell.isDisposed())
            if(!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
    }

    /**
     * A custom composite for displaying either two Combos or two Texts
     */
    class MyComposite extends Composite {
        /** Combos */
        Combo combo1, combo2;

        /** Texts */
        Text text1, text2;

        MyComposite() {
            super(shell, SWT.NONE);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
        }

        /** create the combos */
        void createCombos() {
            combo1 = new Combo(this, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
            combo1.setText("foo");
            combo2 = new Combo(this, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
            combo2.setText("bar");
        }

        /** create the texts */
        void createTexts() {
            text1 = new Text(this, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
            text1.setText("foo");
            text2 = new Text(this, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
            text2.setText("bar");
        }

        /** dispose all children */
        void disposeAll() {
            for(Widget w : getChildren()) {
                w.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    class ButtonListener extends SelectionAdapter {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // erase all
            composite.disposeAll();

            // re-add widgets according to radio button state
            if(button1.getSelection()) {
                composite.createTexts();
            }
            else {
                composite.createCombos();
            }

            // re-do layout and fit the shell
            shell.layout();
            shell.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Phineas. I am going to try out this approach. Will let u know in case of any concerns :)